Finding the dual of a convex problem with inequality constrains
I practice some exercises from Amir Beck's book "Introduction to Nonlinear Optimization" and
I wanna find the dual problem of the primal problem which is given by:
$$\text{min } \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i*ln(x_i)-x_i) \\\text{s.t. } Ax\leq b \\x>0 $$
Where $\text{A} \in R^ {m \times n} \text{ and  b } \in R^m   $. So far I tried to construct the Lagrangian of  the problem and solve it:
The lagrangian is given by:
$$ L (x,\lambda)=\sum_i^n (x_iln(x_i)-x_i)-\lambda^T(Ax-b) \text{ where } \lambda \in R^n _+    $$
Then I tried to apply the gradient operator and I got
$$
\begin{pmatrix} ln(x_1) \\ \vdots \\ ln(x_1) \end{pmatrix} \;
+A^T\lambda
= 0 $$
Thanks!

kindly include your existing workings.

First correction: $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}_+^m$.
Minor computational mistake.
$$
\begin{pmatrix} \ln(x_1) \\ \vdots \\ \ln(x_n) \end{pmatrix} \;
\color{red}-A^T\lambda
= 0 $$
We have $x_i = \exp(e_i^TA^T\lambda )$ where $e_i$ is the $i$-th standard unit vector.
$$x_i = \exp((Ae_i)^T\lambda)=\exp(A_i^T\lambda)$$ where $A_i$ is the $i$-th column of $A$.
Using the above, we can compute our dual:
\begin{align}&\max_{\lambda \ge 0} \min_x \sum_{i=1}^n(x_i \ln (x_i)-x_i)-\lambda^T(Ax-b) \\
&=\max_{\lambda \ge 0}  -\sum_{i=1}^n \exp(A_i^T\lambda )+\lambda^Tb \\\end{align}

you are the best!
